# How to install Cyipopt in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, installation, ipopt

I am trying to install [Cyipopt](https://github.com/matthias-k/cyipopt) in Ubuntu 16.04 for Python 2.7.

I have successfully installed Ipopt, Cython and Lapack

However when I try to install Cyipopt using `python setup.py install`, I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 100, in <module>
main_unix()
File "setup.py", line 94, in main_unix
**pkgconfig('ipopt'))])
File "setup.py", line 81, in pkgconfig
kw['include_dirs'] += [np.get_include()]
KeyError: 'include_dirs'
```

I have been searching the web, but not able to get any hits. Will appreciate any help on this.